# How do I install recessed lights in a metal framed ceiling?

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting

I live a building with metal framing used in the walls and ceiling. I am looking to add some recessed lights to parts of my home but am having difficulty figuring out what the best approach is.

I have attached some photographs I took from a small hatch panel to provide an example of what I have to work with. Looking for suggestions on recommended approach to secure the recessed lights.  There are other rooms where I don't have an access panel, so will need to get them through a 6" hole.

Two answer some questions:

- ceiling is standard drywall
- when using the old work recessed lights, what would be the recommended way attach to something to get some support?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the ceiling panels made of?

Comment: Standard drywall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the ceiling is up already just use standard "old-work" recessed cans. You don't even need "IC" cans since there is no insulation.

Comment: He is what I am talking about:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-6-in-Remodel-Non-Insulation-Contact-Recessed-Housing-H7RT/100092926

Comment: And the 4" variety:
http://www.amazon.com/Halo-H99RT-Recessed-Housing-Remodels/dp/B000HMCG44

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking, is there any concern with weight of recessed lights just sitting on this type of ceiling?

Comment: No. Structurally that is no different than any other sheetrock ceiling.

Comment: Great. One more stupid question, do you happen to know what material this support is made of? I want to figure out placement of lights by determining where the bars are.

Comment: The sheetrock is screwed to hat channel. It's light gauge steel like metal studs are made of.